# What should I do with peer dependencies of dependencies when I develop a library?

Tags: npm, package.json, pnpm, peer-dependencies

Here the situation :
I work on a library that has dependencies which themselves have peer-dependencies.

When doing a `pnpm install`, of course I have an error because of unresolved peer-dependencies.

Also, the library does not use these peer-dependencies.

What should I do ? use `.npmrc` to auto-install them ? forward them as peer-dependency ?
another thing ?

(Note : the library was initially using npm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess just use [auto-install-peers=true](https://pnpm.io/npmrc#auto-install-peers) in your `.npmrc`. This setting will be `true` by default from pnpm v8.

Alternatively, you may install the missing peer dependencies as dev dependencies of you package.

There is no need to add them to peer dependencies unless you use them in code.